# How to change the WordPress Plugin Watson Assistant Chatbot BOX Size?

Tags: plugins, css, user-interface, admin-css

How to change the Wordpress Plugin Watson Assistant Chatbot BOX Size?
The CSS code below changes the height from below to top but not from top to below. I want to decrease the chatbot BOX size from top to below but I am not able to do it.
The Code is written in adittional css part of wordpress .

```
@media (min-width: 640px) {
#watson-float {
top: 0;
right: 0 !important;
}

#watson-box {
width: 35vw !important;
height: 95vh !important;
}

#message-container {
height: calc(100% – 2.75em) !important;
}
}
```

I want to change the size of the box up to the red line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-top and change values according to your will.

```
  @media (min-width: 640px) {
      #watson-float {
            margin-top: 100px;
        top: 0;
        right: 0 !important;
      }
    
      #watson-box {
        width: -900% !important;
        height:100% !important;
      }
    
      #message-container {
        height: calc(100% - 2.75em) !important;
      }
    }
```